# Not able to inject the DataSource using with @RefreshScope of spring cloud config

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-cloud

I am trying to connect to mysql for the same requirement using RefreshScope and it throws the following error

```
Could not obtain connection to query metadata : Error creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.userDataSource' defined in class path resource [com/concretepage/UserConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method 'userDataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not load JDBC driver class [default driver]
2018-02-14 02:24:05.844  WARN 8920 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userEntityManager' defined in class path resource [com/concretepage/UserConfig.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
2018-02-14 02:24:05.846  INFO 8920 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2018-02-14 02:24:05.859  WARN 8920 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase       : The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named [Abandoned connection cleanup thread] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:143)
com.mysql.cj.jdbc.AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.run(AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.java:43)
2018-02-14 02:24:05.890  INFO 8920 --- [           main] utoConfigurationReportLoggingInitializer :
```

Below is the code where I have initialized the properties in userDataSource bean

```
@Configuration
//@PropertySource({ "classpath:application.properties" })
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.concretepage", entityManagerFactoryRef = "userEntityManager", transactionManagerRef = "userTransactionManager")

public class UserConfig {

    @Value("${jdbc.driverClassName: default driver}")
    private String driver;

// Properties
    @Bean
    @Primary
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean userEntityManager() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        em.setDataSource(userDataSource());
        em.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "com.concretepage" });

        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        HashMap<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
        properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", hbm2ddl);
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect", dialect);
        em.setJpaPropertyMap(properties);

        return em;
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean
    @RefreshScope
    public DataSource userDataSource() {

        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(driver);
        dataSource.setUrl(url);
        dataSource.setUsername(usename);
        dataSource.setPassword(password);

        return dataSource;
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager userTransactionManager() {

        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(userEntityManager().getObject());
        return transactionManager;
    }
}
```

This code works with out using RefreshScope. Did I do anything wrong with the configuration?

Comment: are you changing datasource properties on the fly through config server?

Comment: @pvpkiran iam not able to execute code it self when i was trying to run application when using RefreshScope , otherwise it is working normally. my end goal is to change the datasource properties on the fly using refresh RefreshScope

Comment: @pvpkiran  my RefreshScope is working now , but how ever my  datasource property changes successfully reflected while iam hitting the /refresh end point . But the thing is when iam hitting the refresh end point there is no new connection established with new properties. any help would be much appreciated?

Comment: As I told you in the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48744320/dynamic-database-property-changes-in-springboot. Config server is not meant to handle these scenarios or atleast there is no documentation regarding this. So you ahve to test it and see for which cases it can work and for which cases it doesn't

Comment: If you fixed your problem please post an answer to your question.

Comment: @JensSchauder iam just changed my pom.xml Spring cloud dependency version (ie) "<version>Dalston.RELEASE</version> " .